# URL build with Form removing duplicate values

Tags: jquery, forms, url, search, joomla

I have created a custom Search on a Joomla 3 Site. The Search form builds an URL depending on the choices you make. The Search is returning all Taged Articles with the exactly matched Search, this works just fine UNTIL you have a duplicate value, then the Search result returns nothing.

The duplicate value is possible because it is a "search engine" to paste different materials with each other and therefore you can select the same material twice, thus returning the same value.

URL http://www.ego.pc-helfer.eu/produktsuche/untergruende

If i select every first open from the above URL it will return me the following URL when hitting "Suchen":

http://www.ego.pc-helfer.eu/index.php?option=com_tags&view=tag&id[0]=4&id[1]=4&id[2]=64&id[3]=67&id[4]=69&types[0]=1

where we have value 1 (&id[0]=4) and value 2 (&id[1]=4) are the same in this cas the second value should be removed from the URL.

I am working with the following code to build the URL (it looks nasty):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#Suchen').on('click', function() {
        var URLBase = "/index.php?option=com_tags&view=tag";
var TrailingFixedData = "&types[0]=1";

finalURL = URLBase + document.getElementById('Metalle Legierungen 1').value + document.getElementById('Mineralische Untergruende 1').value + document.getElementById('Anstriche Beschichtungen').value + document.getElementById('Keramik').value + document.getElementById('Glas').value +document.getElementById('Spiegel').value + document.getElementById('Stein').value + document.getElementById('Kunststoffe').value + document.getElementById('Bitumen').value + document.getElementById('Dichtfolien').value + document.getElementById('Pappe').value + document.getElementById('Holz Holzwerkstoffe Laminat').value + document.getElementById('Metalle Legierungen 2').value + document.getElementById('Mineralische Untergruende 2').value + document.getElementById('Anstriche Beschichtungen 2').value + document.getElementById('Keramik 2').value + document.getElementById('Glas 2').value +document.getElementById('Spiegel 2').value + document.getElementById('Stein 2').value + document.getElementById('Kunststoffe 2').value + document.getElementById('Bitumen 2').value + document.getElementById('Dichtfolien 2').value + document.getElementById('Pappe 2').value + document.getElementById('Holz Holzwerkstoffe Laminat 2').value + document.getElementById('Substratverbindung').value + document.getElementById('Witterung').value + document.getElementById('Produkteinsatz').value + TrailingFixedData;
        window.location.replace(finalURL);
    });
});
</script>
```

First step (I think), i have to clean up the code and work mit variables, something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#Suchen').on('click', function() {
        var URLBase = "/index.php?option=com_tags&view=tag";
VALUE1 = document.getElementById('Metalle Legierungen 1').value OR document.getElementById('Mineralische Untergruende 1').value  OR document.getElementById('Anstriche Beschichtungen').value; // and so on, i used OR because i don't now how to combine this
VALUE2 = document.getElementById('Metalle Legierungen 2').value OR document.getElementById('Mineralische Untergruende 2').value OR document.getElementById('Anstriche Beschichtungen 2').value;
var TrailingFixedData = "&types[0]=1";

finalURL = URLBase + VALUE1 + VALUE2  + TrailingFixedData;
        window.location.replace(finalURL);
    });
});
</script>
```

No to strip VALUE2 from the URL when it equals VALUE1 i will probably have to use an IF statement to strip it from the URL. Or am i thinking completely wrong her?

Hope everything is clear